# How to modify a string while preserving its original index as reference?

Tags: arrays, string, list, algorithm, format

I'm looking for a computationally efficient way to add and remove elements from a string at will using its original index as reference. A good example I have in mind is to be able to format a text using html tags:

Given the following string `Lorem Ipsum`, I would like to be able to warp the word `Ipsum` with a `b` tag, such as `Lorem <b>Ipsum</b>`, and then delete these tags and add a new line between the two words, such as `Lorem <br> Ispum`, etc.

Of course, every time I'd add or remove an element, the string index is modified and I loose the ability to use the original index to modify the string. The method I came up with so far is to assign every character its original index, such as `(0, 'L'), (1, 'o'), (2, 'r'), (3, 'e'), ...`  and then tinker in-between this original index and the one of the modified string.

This is highly inefficient, and formatting a big string, such as a book chapter, is too slow to support on-the-fly interaction with the text.

Is there a way to implement this properly ? I'm sure this is a common algorithmic problem but I guess I lack the vocabulary to look it up since I couldn't find anything so far.

Comment: Maybe using not a single string but a list of substrings each attached with its tag decorations? Or a tree of strings? Question is slightly too broad.

Comment: As @Jean-BaptisteYunès says, the question is slightly too broad. I agree (but might quibble with "slightly"). As worded I don't think there will be much interest in the question and that any answers will be of limited value to you. On the other hand, if you were to focus the question on a particular task, and set out your objectives, there might be considerable interest in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally:

1. Store the text in a data structure that divides it into blocks so that it can be more efficiently modified, like a [rope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rope_(data_structure)).
2. In each block, keep back-pointers to all of the references that point to text positions within the block, and adjust them whenever the content of a block changes.

This sort of problem arises in the implementation of most text editors.